# Script is before /body but it runs before page is loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, load, order-of-execution

I am new to web developing and I am trying node.js with express.

I have the following directory structure:

**First App**
----**node_modules**
----**public**
--------**scripts**
------------*additems.js*
----**views**
--------*home.ejs*
----*app.js*

with bold is a folder and italic is a file.

this is the file additem.js:

```
console.log("js connected");
alert("test");
```

and this is home.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test Node</title>
</head> 
<body>       
   <h1>Dynamic Page</h1>
   <p></p>   
   <ol id='olist'>Names List</ol>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/scripts/additems.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

console.log("Server has been started!");

//app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    //res.send("Home Page");
     res.render("home.ejs");

 })
```

**The problem that the javascript is being run before the page is loaded**

I know this because the alert message is appearing before anything else. In addition I tried to use some DOM elements but they have been returned as undefined.

Searching the net I can see that my script position is correct just before the  tag, and supposedly it should run last.

**What am I missing here?**

I am aware of the possibility of using the onload event, but I want to avoid it unless it is a must, beside **I want to learn why the script is not run at last as it supposed to do.**

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

Thanks Scott Marcus for your contribution which helped me solving the problem.

In fact, there was a double error.

1- I used alert() and that is cannot be a hint as you mentioned.
2- I did not mention the code after the alert() because I copied it from a trusted website and I wanted the question to be as short as possible. However,  the code had an error that prevented it from being run in the correct way.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **The problem that the javascript is being run before the page is loaded**
>
> I know this because the alert message is appearing before anything
>   else.

**You can't be blamed for coming to that conclusion, but it's actually not the case.**

`alert()`'s are processed by the operating system asynchronously from the JavaScript that spawned them and can usually be rendered faster than the JavaScript can execute. Additionally, an `alert()` is a "blocking" API call, it freezes the UI so that rendering doesn't sync up with processing.

Instead of an `alert()` use a `console.log()`. You will find that doing so shows that your code is running when it should.

Here's an example of how an `alert()` can mislead your interpretation of the flow of a sequence.

```js
console.clear();
console.log("test before alert()");
alert("Look at the console. Notice how you don't see the log message that came before me?\nEven though the JavaScript received the instruction to write to the console, the OS can render an alert() faster than that.");
```

Here's the same concept again, but this time without offloading any work to the OS:

```js
console.clear();
console.log("test before console.log()");
console.log("Look at the console. Notice how you now do see the log message that came before me?");
```

Comment: Why the down vote. This ***is*** the correct answer.

Comment: even without alert it runs after as I had tried to use some DOM elements, but they returned as `undefined` and I get this error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined` in the chrome console. I commented this part of the code to eliminate errors sources.

Comment: @Shadi Then there is something else going on because when the script is at the bottom of the page (after all the HTML elements), the DOM will be built by the time the script is encountered.

Comment: this is what I am trying to know!

Comment: Thanks @Scott Marcus I found the error in code and everything is working as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

Having your script at the end of the body is an outdated pattern. You should prefer to load the script in the `head` with the `defer` attribute (read more https://mdn.io/script). If you can't do that, in your script you may use a load listener to delay execution until all loading is complete.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {console.log('tada!')});
```

Comment: You have this exactly backwards. Putting scripts at the end of the `body` is a very mainstream and highly recommended pattern. Registering an event handler takes more memory and CPU resources.

Comment: I'm afraid that "everyone else is doing it" is not a valid reason for using a suboptimal pattern. I'll defer to Google to explain the downsides to render blocking JavaScript to you https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/adding-interactivity-with-javascript#parser_blocking_versus_asynchronous_javascript

Comment: Your explanations and documentation certainly do explain how to have a `script` element in the `head` section successfully. Or, you can avoid all of that and put the script at the bottom of the page, which blocks nothing and avoids the extra overhead of registering an event handler. In short, you are making an argument that isn't applicable to what I'm talking about. And, it's not an "everyone else is doing it thing", it's a well-know best practice thing. There's no arguing that less code that results in less memory and less CPU work is better than the opposite.

Comment: You're focusing on the event listener which was a separate suggestion. When the browser reads the html file, if your script is in the body, it will load the script before it finishes loading the DOM. When you use defer it waits for your DOM content to finish loading. This is why it's not render blocking.

Comment: See the ["Put scripts at bottom"](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) section of this best-practice article from Yahoo (among many, many others).

Comment: *if your script is in the body, it will load the script before it finishes loading the DOM.* That is unequivocally false. I don't know where in the world you came up with such a ludicrous statement. Browsers read from left to right, top to bottom and by the time the browser reaches the `</body>`, the DOM is completely built - always.

Comment: Looks like that Yahoo page was written in 2009. "An alternative suggestion that often comes up is to use deferred scripts. The DEFER attribute indicates that the script does not contain document.write, and is a clue to browsers that they can continue rendering. Unfortunately, Firefox doesn't support the DEFER attribute."

Firefox has supported defer since version 3.5 released in 2009.

Comment: HTML page processing hasn't changed since 1998. You are absolutely and completely mistaken about how the DOM is built and how user-agents read/process pages.

Comment: You are completely missing the point and conflating two different things. I'm not saying that putting the script at the top and using DEFER won't work, I'm saying it's more expensive to do so than simply putting the script at the bottom. The guidance from YAHOO and virtually everyone else hasn't changed because page processing hasn't changed.

Comment: Page processing may not have changed, but best practices have changed. Your article was from before the HTML 5 spec was finalised where they ADDED `defer` to serve this purpose. I'm not just saying that defer works, I'm saying it's INCORRECT as per the specification to not use `async` or `defer`. Whether or not it's more expensive is irrelevant, that is a small price to pay to have your assets localised correctly and not using an antiquated hack

Comment: Ok, well you go right on adding more code that, if not configured properly, will cause bugs and if configured properly will run slower that in needs to. Also, I think it's great that you found something that "works" and will not even consider logical reasons for not using it, even though that's not what modern coding best-practices recommend.

Comment: Hey, you might also want to tell the folks at JQuery that [they are using JQuery wrong](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) 
 and that their approach is outdated.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox have had bug free implementations of the defer attribute for 8 years, so I'm fairly confident it's not going to introduce any bugs. and sorry, that's the specification which is by definition modern best-practice.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, you'll notice that `$.ready()` is equivalent (enough) to `DOMContentLoaded`, whose definition according to MDN is `The DOM is loaded, parsed and ready`. Interestingly, `DOMContentLoaded` will fire *after* any `script`s at the bottom have run and executed, so by that definition, the DOM is *not ready* at that point.

Comment: See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/he6tzdfd/2/) demonstrating that scripts before `</body>` execute before `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: You are still stuck on the implementation of DEFER, which is not something that I have brought up at all, you did. I'm saying that if someone were to follow your guidance and forget to include DEFER or to misspell it, they've got a bug. As a general rule, spanning all disciplines, if you have to do extra work (and thus introducing more opportunities for mistakes) to do something that can be done just as well (or in this case better) without that extra work, then the extra work path is a mistake.

Comment: Scripts being executed are not part of the DOM building process. The DOM is separate from script execution.

Comment: Correct, unless you have scripts that want to query / manipulate the DOM. In that case, you'd want to make sure the DOM is ready by the time you want to use it.

Comment: This has gone circular. The simple fact is this - any script placed just before the closing `body` tag will run when the DOM is ready. Your example @BryceHanscomb does show the slightest of timing differences because the closing `body` and closing `html` tags haven't been processed yet. But, this is actually a good thing because the script can run just a little bit sooner than the official DOMContentLoaded event with full confidence that all the DOM elements have been fully parsed and are available. And, this is all done without using memory/CPU to store and invoke an event callback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166433/discussion-between-bryce-hanscomb-and-scott-marcus).

Answer (score 0):

It takes time for the browser to parse your HTML and build the DOM, and your script will start running as soon as it is encountered, so basically you're setting up a race and hoping the js interpreter loses. Not a reliable way to run asynchronous code.

Comment: So,what is the correct way? if you can illustrate according to my code that will be even better.

Comment: The browser will not encounter the script until after is has completed parsing the HTML. There is no "race condition".

Comment: Shadi — Pretty sure window.onload or $(document).ready() are the only ways to do this properly.

Comment: Scott — That's right, it won't run the script until it parses, but the parsing happens before the creation of the DOM.