# placing <script> tags right before </body> doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Im watching a tutorial in which the mentor suggests that in order to improve the user experience it is better to add `<script>` tags right before the `</body>` , so the script runs after the page content is fully loaded.

I try this block of code and I expect to see the "hello world!" before any script runs but my browser runs the javascript before everything else shows up (displays only a blank page with the alert box)

```
<html>
 <body>

  <p>hello world!</p>

  <script>
   alert('hey there');
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

I tried this with safari/chrome/opera and got the same result. I know I can use jQuery to solve this but can someone explain this behaviour?

---

Thanks to @T.J.Crowder , I marked the correct answer, just in case anyone is curious about what is happening under the hood I've found a good explanation here: 
[Script is before /body but it runs before page is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49164143/5950111)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make sure a Javascript script is first to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387200/make-sure-a-javascript-script-is-first-to-run)

Comment: I guess "the page content is fully loaded" is an overstatement. It's not fully loaded, it's just interpreted and the elements exists there for you to use but doesn't mean it's rendered.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load Check out this link. It answers your question.

Comment: Most modern browsers wait until the script finishes before rendering the page.

Comment: @sodali_ayran - That's asking a different question, and while most of the solutions there will work (because they suggest a poor antipattern, using the window `load` event), it's not a good candidate for closing this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...so the script runs after the page content is fully loaded.

Correct, all the elements above it are parsed and in the DOM — **but**, the browser may or may not have had a chance to *render* them yet. To give it a chance to do so, through a very small delay into your code.

```
    <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('hey there');
    }, 50);
    </script>
</body>
```

Live Example:

```html
<p>hello world!</p>
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    alert('hey there');
}, 50);
</script>
```

That adds a 50ms delay — nothing a human being is going to notice. But if you want the absolute minimum delay:

```
    <script>
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('hey there');
        }, 0);
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Live Example:

```html
<p>hello world!</p>
<script>
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('hey there');
    }, 0);
});
</script>
```

More:

- [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)
- [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/window/setTimeout)

Those won't wait for all images and such to load, though. If you want to wait for **everything** (which could be a long way), use the [`window` `load` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load), see that link or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/807895/157247) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

When a script tag is placed at the bottom of the body tag, it simply means that the rest of the DOM is processed before the script runs. It does not guarantee that the page has fully rendered.

You can use the [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event to ensure that the page has rendered:

```html
<html>
 <body>

  <p>hello world!</p>

  <script>
   alert('hey there');
   
   window.onload = function() {
      alert("Page has rendered");
   };
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `load` happens **very** late in the page load process, after everything (including all images) have been loaded. It's generally not what you want (though it could be in this specific case).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  alert('hey there');
});
```

It is the vanilla js equivalent of [jquery document ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Edit: main difference from window onload in Nisarg Shah's answer that this doesnt wait until the site is fully loaded (external styles, images etc)

Comment: Do note that `DOMContentLoaded` doesn't wait for dependent resources to load: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: ...and may well fire before rendering occurs, just as it does in the OP's example.